# Last text box far off to the side

Tags: php, html, zurb-foundation

I've been working on a large form using Foundation. On my last row of text boxes, the last text box is far off to the right side rather than next to the 39th text box. I used PHP to build the form, I copy pasted the HTML output into jsfiddle.  Any ideas?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qre6/3/

PHP:

```
 <?php
              //$counter = 0;
              echo "<form id='scoreI'>\n";
              echo "<div class='row'>\n";
              for($counter = 1; $counter <= 40; $counter++) 
              {
                $boxNumber = 'box' . $counter;
                echo "<div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>\n";
                echo "<label>$counter.";
                echo "<input type='text' name='$boxNumber' id='$boxNumber' /> </label>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
                if($counter%12==0) 
                {                  
                  echo "</div>\n";
                  echo "<div class='row'>\n";
                }
                //if($counter == 40) {continue;}
              }
              echo "</div>\n";
              echo "</form>\n";
            ?>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>1.<input id='box1' name='box1' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>2.<input id='box2' name='box2' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>3.<input id='box3' name='box3' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>4.<input id='box4' name='box4' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>5.<input id='box5' name='box5' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>6.<input id='box6' name='box6' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>7.<input id='box7' name='box7' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>8.<input id='box8' name='box8' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>9.<input id='box9' name='box9' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>10.<input id='box10' name='box10' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>11.<input id='box11' name='box11' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>12.<input id='box12' name='box12' type='text'></label>
    </div>
</div>

<!--repeat above twice-->

<div class='row'>
    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>37.<input id='box37' name='box37' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>38.<input id='box38' name='box38' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>39.<input id='box39' name='box39' type='text'></label>
    </div>

    <div class='large-1 small-1 columns testBox'>
        <label>40.<input id='box40' name='box40' type='text'></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I added the wrong link, my apologies.

Comment: I want to move the last text box (#40) to be right next to the 39th rather than far off to the side

Comment: @kevinabelita, my apologies I added the wrong link.

Comment: yeah, the first link on the question didn't make sense, it doesn't reflect the one inside the question.

Comment: I was looking at a Foundation experiment that someone had put up on Codepen - my mistake

Comment: is this like you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/7qre6/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put them in proper order. You want to use `block-grid` [(as used in the manual](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html)). Consider this example:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-12">
        <?php for($x = 1; $x <= 40; $x++): ?>
            <li><?php echo "$x."; ?><input type="text" name="<?php echo 'box'.$x; ?>" id="<?php echo 'box'.$x; ?>" /></li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qre6/6/)**